# Sync Google contact photo to Android phone

Tags: contacts, gmail

I created a contact a while back of a friend, just her name and mobile number. Today I added her Gmail address to the phonebook in her contact card.

When I go into [Gmail Contacts](https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#contacts) I see her Google+ photo - How can I get my phone to sync that photo.

FYI - We are not friends on Google+

Answer (score 1):

After some playing I figured it out.

I went to the App Manager - found Contacts and Contact Storage (cleared the cache from Contacts and cleared all data from Contact Storage)

After recreating my profile an automatic sync took place and all my contacts came back with associated Gmail contact photos

Comment: Also check out the Find and Merge Duplicate Contacts on http://contacts.google.com under the More link. It should merge the email contact with the phone contact.